# Laptop audio randomly switches between speakers and headphones jack

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, speakers, headphones

The audio on my Dell Inspiron laptop (running Windows 10) is acting up. One minute it's sounding fine, then suddenly it goes away, then comes back a few seconds later.

I've tried listening to audio using wired headphones and discovered that when the audio stops on the built-in speakers, it's channeled to the headphones jack. But even with headphones jacked in, audio flips from them to the speakers and back, randomly.

When I use bluetooth headphones the problem goes away - sound is channeled to the wireless headphones consistently over time.

**What is causing this odd behavior and how can I fix it?**

My laptop's model is [Dell Inspiron 13-7352](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-il/product-support/product/inspiron-13-7352-laptop/docs). It's running Windows 10 (10.0.18363 build 18363).

Comment: It could be a faulty headphone socket. The fix would require some soldering.

Comment: There may be a loose contact between the headphones and the jack...Either of them may be faulty.